# NgRx store selector unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, selector, ngrx, store

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        this.format = this.store.select(selectUserSettings).pipe(
          filter(
            (userSettings: UserSettingsState) =>
              Boolean(userSettings) && !userSettings.errors && !userSettings.isLoading && !!userSettings.localizationProfile
          ),
          map((userSettings: UserSettingsState) =>
            userSettings.localizationProfile.dateFormat.toLocaleLowerCase().replace('mm', 'MM')
          ),
          takeUntil(this.destroy)
        );
      }
```

How can I write the unit test for this function? I tried to mock the selector like `mockUserSettingsSelector = store.overrideSelector(selectUserSettings, initialState.userSettings);` ,
and the test

```
    describe('OverdueTableComponent', () => {
  let component: OverdueTableComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<OverdueTableComponent>;
  let store: MockStore;
  const initialState: SettingsState = new SettingsInitialState();
  let mockUserSettingsSelector: MemoizedSelector<SettingsState, UserSettingsState>;

  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [OverdueTableComponent, OverdueEventTypeTranslationComponent],
        imports: [SimplebarAngularModule, StoreModule.forRoot({}), StoreModule.forFeature('settings', settingsReducer)],
        providers: [OverdueTableComponent, OverdueEventTypeTranslationComponent, provideMockStore({ initialState })],
      }).compileComponents();
    })
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OverdueTableComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
    mockUserSettingsSelector = store.overrideSelector(selectUserSettings, initialState.userSettings);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('format should not be null', () => {
    mockUserSettingsSelector.setResult({
      errors: undefined,
      isLoading: false,
      localizationProfile: {
        currency: 'dummy-currency',
        currencySymbol: 'dummy-currency-symbol',
        dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
        language: 'English (British)',
        timezone: 'dummy-timezone',
      },
      successfullyUpdated: false,
    });
    store.refreshState();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component.format).not.toBe(null);
  });
});
```

but without any result.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `component.ngOnInit()` before setting the mocked value hence it will not be set.

Please be aware that the first `fixture.detectChanges()` will also trigger the `ngOnInit` method. In case this is called inside a `beforeEach`, you would need to remove it from there and place it inside your test cases after the setup is done (and you could remove the explicit trigger of `ngOnInit`)

---

Edit:

```
describe('OverdueTableComponent', () => {
  ...

  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      ...
    })
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OverdueTableComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
    mockUserSettingsSelector = store.overrideSelector(selectUserSettings, initialState.userSettings);
    // PLEASE REMOVE THIS LINE fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges(); // ADD THE CHANGE DETECTION HERE
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('format should not be null', () => {
    mockUserSettingsSelector.setResult({
      errors: undefined,
      isLoading: false,
      localizationProfile: {
        currency: 'dummy-currency',
        currencySymbol: 'dummy-currency-symbol',
        dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
        language: 'English (British)',
        timezone: 'dummy-timezone',
      },
      successfullyUpdated: false,
    });
    store.refreshState();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // REMOVE THIS LINE as fixture.detectChanges() does it for you 
    // component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component.format).not.toBe(null);
  });
});
```

uncovered lines:
[image]

Comment: I moved the component.ngOnInit() after fixture.detectChanges(), but still not working

Comment: Please provide a bit more information on your test, especially the test setup. Also is store.refreshState an async operation?

Comment: As I've written in my answer, you would need to remove the fixture.detectChanges from your beforeEach. The first fixture.detectChanges call inside your test triggers the onInit method inside your component.

Comment: This also means you would need to add it into each `it` block instead (in the first test 'should create' as a first line, and inside your test after the mockStorage)

Comment: I did this, but still have uncovered lines. I edited the question and uploaded a picture of this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226930/discussion-between-erbsenkoenig-and-simpller).